# Generics List<List<T>>

Tags: c#, generics

If I have `List<T>` which got some lists from type `MyClass`, for example `List<List<MyClass>>` and `MyClass` is the parent class from `MyClassB`. Why I can't do the following?

```
List<List<MyClass>> allLists = new List<List<MyClass>>();

List<MyClassB> myList = new List<MyClassB>();
myList.Add(new MyClassB());

//And now the point which dont work
allLists.Add(myList);
```

If I implement a method I can say `SomeClass<T> ... where T : MyClass`, is there something similar for my list problem?

So that I can add lists from any child class to my first-level list?

Comment: Does it throw any error on compile?

Comment: invalid argument on design time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason that you cannot do it is as follows: imagine that `allLists.Add(myList)` worked. Then the compiler would know that `allLists[0]` is a `List<MyClass>`, so the following would be OK:

```
allLists[0].Add(new MyClassX());
```

That would be a runtime error, because `allLists[0]` is actually a `List<MyClassB>`. It is not capable of holding `MyClassX` objects.

If you change your code so that `myList` is a `List<MyClass>`, your code would work:

```
List<MyClass> myList = new List<MyClass>();
myList.Add(new MyClassB()); // This works, because MyClassB extends MyClass
allLists.Add(myList); // This works, too
```

Answer (score 9):

```
class Animal {}
class Tiger : Animal {}
class Giraffe : Animal {}
...
List<Giraffe> giraffes = new List<Giraffe>();
List<List<Animal>> lists = new List<List<Animal>>();
lists.Add(giraffes); // Illegal!
```

Your question is "why is that illegal?"  The answer is: suppose it were legal and let's keep going...

```
List<Animal> animals = lists[0]; // Obviously typesafe.
animals.Add(new Tiger()); // Obviously typesafe
```

And we just added a tiger to a list of giraffes.

Since the two latter steps are obviously typesafe, the place that cannot be typesafe must be `Add(giraffes)`.

Now, as of C# 4, this does work:

```
List<IEnumerable<Animal>> lists = new List<IEnumerable<Animal>>();
lists.Add(giraffes);
```

Why is that legal?  Because there is no `Add` method on `IEnumerable<T>`:

```
IEnumerable<Animal> animals = lists[0];
```

And now we can't violate type safety because there's no way to put a tiger into that list of giraffes if we only are accessing it via `IEnumerable<T>`.

By the way, someone asks this question almost every day. Do a web search for "C# covariance and contravariance" and you'll get a lot more information about it.

Comment: He certainly does.  Listen to the Lippert!  Testify!

Comment: @KenKin: I find it much more intuitive to reason "a giraffe is a kind of animal" than "a MyClassA is a MyClassB". Jon Skeet likes "an apple is a kind of fruit", which is fine, but I like saying "giraffe". It's a fun word to say. Try it!  Giraffe giraffe giraffe giraffe giraffe!

Comment: I think examples with animals are lovely, especcially since I just endured 2 days of examples based on killing people with axes (my coworker was explaining to someone how DNS works...) +1 for letting me stay sane today :)

Comment: @Arie: Oh sure, the standard killing-people-with-axes explanation of Internet name lookup mechanisms. Everyone knows that, right? Of course I prefer DHCP, which is as we all know much more like setting abandoned warehouses on fire...

Comment: @EricLippert: Seems the two most intuitive collections are both taken. Got no idea to name something better. BTW, the pronounce of that IEnumerable<Giraffe> sounds fun.

Comment: @KenKin: There are lots of standard hierarchies. Best to avoid Shape-Quadrilateral-Square as that one has difficulties. Person-Employee-Manager is common. Vehicle-Car-Ferrari. Publication-Newspaper-NewYorkTimes. You can come up with real-world examples all day.

Comment: @EricLippert: Thanks for the idea. But I guess that animals and fruit still be top two for most understandable.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use as the inner collection an interface that allows derived classes (called [covariant interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997386.aspx)):

```
var allLists = new List<IEnumerable<MyClass>>();
```

Comment: The term you seem to be looking for is an interface that's *covariant* in it's generic argument.  Also note that this may not be a valid solution for the OP if they really are used as lists, and not just sequences.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<List<MyClass>> allLists = new List<List<MyClass>>();
```

the list you are adding is the not same type. 
You may do like this:

```
interface IMyClass
{
    //some properties
}
```

All your child classes must inherit from IMyClass. Then you will have list like this.

```
List<List<IMyClass>> allLists = new List<List<IMyClass>>();
```

Comment: Yes for sure. But the type of the List iam adding is extended from the type. So normaly it should work. But because the type here is List and not myclass the compiler cant dissolving this. I need a solution where this is possible.

Comment: @Sebi `So normaly it should work.`  Not, it shouldn't.  A `List` is, by it's very nature, invariant in the type of it's generic argument.  It's not that the compiler isn't smart enough to know that this works, it's that there truly is no way to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that AllLists is strongly-typed to contain lists of MyClass.  MyList is strongly-typed to contain instances of MyClassB.

Whereas you'd be able to store List in your List>, there is a type mismatch in your current code.

Answer (score 0):

This will fix the issue:

```
List<MyClass> myList = new List<MyClass>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the compiler that MyClass is the parent from MyClassB i think. [This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564%28v=vs.80%29.aspx#csharp_generics_topic4) about the `where` keyword may help you further

Answer (score 0):

Even though MyClassB is a sub type of MyClass, it doesn't mean that List is a sub type of List. The question you want to ask is why List isn't covariant with T (which would cause List to be a subtype of List where T is a subtype of Y. Look up the terms covariance and contravariance.

The answer is two fold. Firstly List was implemented before C# implemented co- and contravariance. But most importantly, you can only be covariant if T is an "out" type. 
Since you can shove stuff into a list, it is not an out type. IEnumerable only emits objects of type T. Therefore, it can be covariant.

Comment: `Firstly List was implemented before C# implemented co- and contravariance.` That's not an issue.  Changing a type to be covariant in it's generic argument is not a breaking change.  `IEnumerable<T>` was changed in C# 4.0 to add covariance to `T`.