# Create list of classes derived from a base class - There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, c#-10.0

I am creating the following list of `Strategy<Option>`:

```
List<Runner<Strategy<Options>>> runners = new List<Runner<Strategy<Options>>> {
  new Runner<MonthlyStrategy>(new MonthlyStrategy(x => { x.Window = 2000; }))
};
```

I will add Strategies that derive from `Strategy<Options>` but I get the error:

```
There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'strategy' of 'Runner<MonthlyStrategy>.Runner(string, MonthlyStrategy)'
The type 'MonthlyStrategy' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'Runner<T>'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'MonthlyStrategy' to 'Strategy<Options>'
```

My code is the following:

```
public class Options { }

public interface IStrategy<T> where T: Options {
  T Options { get; }
}

public abstract class Strategy<T> : IStrategy<T> where T : Options {
  public abstract T Options { get; }
  public Strategy(Action<T> options) {
    options(Options);
  }
}

public class Runner<T> where T : Strategy<Options> {
  public T Strategy { get; } 
  public Runner(String cron, T strategy) {  
    Strategy = strategy;
  } 
} 

public class MontlhyStrategyOptions : Options { 
  public Int32 Window { get; set; }= 10; 
} 

public class MonthlyStrategy : Strategy<MontlhyStrategyOptions> {

  public override MontlhyStrategyOptions Options => new MontlhyStrategyOptions();

  public MonthlyStrategy(Action<MontlhyStrategyOptions> options) : base (options) { }

}
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C# does not support [variance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/) for classes (i.e. in general case `Strategy<MontlhyStrategyOptions>` is not `Strategy<Options>` - [explanation with lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15550439/generics-listlistt)). To achieve something like this you can try migrating to [covariant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/variance-in-generic-interfaces) interfaces:

```cs
public interface IStrategy<out T> where T: Options {
    T Options { get; }
}

public abstract class Strategy<T> : IStrategy<T> where T : Options {
    public abstract T Options { get; }
    public Strategy(Action<T> options) {
        options(Options);
    }
}

public interface IRunner<out T> where T : IStrategy<Options> {}

public class Runner<T> : IRunner<T> where T : IStrategy<Options>
{
    public T Strategy { get; }

    public Runner(String cron, T strategy)
    {
        Strategy = strategy;
    }
}

public class MontlhyStrategyOptions : Options { 
    public Int32 Window { get; set; }= 10; 
}

public class MonthlyStrategy : Strategy<MontlhyStrategyOptions>
{
    public override MontlhyStrategyOptions Options => new MontlhyStrategyOptions();
    public MonthlyStrategy(Action<MontlhyStrategyOptions> options) : base(options)
    {
    }
}
```

And usage:

```cs
List<IRunner<IStrategy<Options>>> runners = new List<IRunner<IStrategy<Options>>> {
    new Runner<MonthlyStrategy>("", new MonthlyStrategy(x => { x.Window = 2000; }))
};
```